# I'm getting Class 'PackageVersions\Versions' not found after running php artisan

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm using MacOs. And have a Laravel project. Running `composer update` produces

```
 Class 'PackageVersions\Versions' not found
```

Running composer install same thing. And even `php artisan` without any other thing produces the same result. The only thing that didn't produce an error is `composer update --no-scripts`

My php version is 7.4, Laravel version is 5.8. Composer version is 2.3.2

This is more from the log before the error is produced after `composer update`

```
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

In base.php line 145:
                                              
  Class 'PackageVersions\Versions' not found  
                                              

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

This is the list of my composer packages on the require param

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.9",
    "eduardokum/laravel-mail-auto-embed": "^1.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
},
```

Comment: Are you using a custom package ? since you're using an old laravel version and the packages available to it, maybe you should try using composer 1 to install everything.

Comment: Please share more details. As `php artisan package:discover --ansi` throws that error, how is Composer related to this?

Comment: Same thing
  - Downgrading myclabs/deep-copy (1.11.0 => 1.9.3): Downloading (100%)         
  - Downgrading phpunit/phpunit (7.5.20 => 7.5.15): Downloading (100%)         
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

In base.php line 145:
                                              
  Class 'PackageVersions\Versions' not found

Comment: @NicoHaase I thought it could be that composer is not installing the necessary packages, which is why I included that it might be a composer issue. I installed php7.4 using homebrew. The project is a bit old, and it was running on php 7.1, unfortunately I couldn't successfully download php 7.1 since it's deprecated, but I thought php 7.4 should be ok? Anyway I'm not sure why the error is happening as well, and have no idea where to look.

Comment: You could check whether `ocramius/package-versions` or `composer/package-versions-deprecated` are installed (check your `composer.lock` for this). If they are not, but any part of your code requires classes from this package (like the error indicates), you should install one of these two packages

Answer (score 6):

`PackageVersions\Versions` has been deprecated, at least according to an [interim package](https://github.com/composer/package-versions-deprecated#package-versions) by Composer.

The specific reasons the dependency isn't being installed for you are not particularly easy to explain, or even understand, but most likely there's a dependency issue with one of your packages. You're probably updating packages and dependencies have changed with new versions. I'll focus on the solution for brevity though.

Composer now ships with `Composer\InstalledVersions` which offers the same functionality as the deprecated package.

Even though it's not listed as one of your packages, I'm to going to guess you're working with Backpack for Laravel based on the file the error is in and the line it's on. Regardless, the solution is simply to replace `\PackageVersions\Versions` with `\Composer\InstalledVersions` in the `base.php` file noted in your error. For Backpack it's `config/backpack/base.php`.

Before:

```php
[
//...
    'cachebusting_string' => \PackageVersions\Versions::getVersion('backpack/crud'),
//...
]
```

After:

```php
[
//...
    'cachebusting_string' => \Composer\InstalledVersions::getVersion('backpack/crud'),
//...
]
```

Note: `Composer\InstalledVersions` is available by default as long as you're using the Composer autoloader, which 99.999% of Composer users are. Read more: https://getcomposer.org/doc/07-runtime.md#installed-versions