# Looking for test/stage environment strategy for Shopware 6 in different versions

Tags: git, testing, version-control, repository, shopware6

i have already develop plugins for Shopware 6. For the development i use [shopware-docker](https://github.com/shyim/shopware-docker).
Now i will **test the plugin in different versions (6.1 - 6.5 *)**. To achieve this goal i installed locally the [Shopware production Template](https://github.com/shopware/production).

By default, the **Branch 6.4.17.2** is selected. After the install routine, everythings work.

But if i checkout to **Branch 6.1**, the webpage are gone with HTTP ERROR 500.

So i try to run `composer install` to recreate the application dependencies for the current branch 6.1.
The command response with:

```
rammi@rammi-laptop-i7:~/Schreibtisch/PROJECTS/ecommerce/shopware-test-environment/shopware-test-environment$ composer install
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 127.0.0.1:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
No composer.lock file present. Updating dependencies to latest instead of installing from lock file. See https://getcomposer.org/install for more information.
> [ ! -f vendor/autoload.php ] || bin/console system:update:prepare
Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 127.0.0.1:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "PackageVersions\Versions" not found in /var/www/ecommerce/shopware-test-environment/bin/console:50
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/ecommerce/shopware-test-environment/bin/console on line 50
Script [ ! -f vendor/autoload.php ] || bin/console system:update:prepare handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with error code 255
```

With an `git pull origin` the answer is:

```
rammi@rammi-laptop-i7:~/Schreibtisch/PROJECTS/ecommerce/shopware-test-environment/shopware-test-environment$ git pull origin
Bereits aktuell.
```

My questions:

- what is a **recommended strategy to test/stage** in diferrent versions?
- is there **a documentation about**?

**Edit #1**

The error seem viniculate to the [deprecated `PackageVersions\Versions`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72723104/2702011) class (inside `bin/console`). Now i am
looking for help, **how to fix this**...

**Edit #2**
To run `composer install` for Branch 6.1 successfully:

- downgrade composer version to 1.* because of [difference between V1 & V2](https://packagist.org/packages/composer/package-versions-deprecated)
- switch to php 7.4

Comment: Perhaps you mean checkout, not pull? pull just means fetch + merge and it seems you or others did not change anything...

Comment: @Christoph thanks for your answer. The pull was only a attempt to see, if everything is ok with the repo, after the checkout to branch 6.1 and the upon described following errors.
It is an unexpected behavior after checkout to 6.1

Comment: I recommend reading https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: @Christoph, i think your recommendation is not very usefull, the errors are based on different composer versions, see my EDIT #1. 
But thanks for your suggests,

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you stop messing about recreating the wheel here. Shopware recommends using the Dockware images for development (and can be configured for production & CI) -> https://dockware.io I myself have used this extensively on Mac, Win10 WSL2 & Linux boxes.

You could set up one shop at a time with a docker-composer file like [so](https://github.com/dockware/examples/blob/master/basic-dev-setup/docker-compose.yml):

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  shop:
    container_name: shop
    image: dockware/dev:latest
    ports:
      - "22:22"     # ssh
      - "80:80"     # apache2
      - "443:443"   # apache2 https
      - "8888:8888" # watch admin
      - "9998:9998" # watch storefront proxy
      - "9999:9999" # watch storefront
      - "3306:3306" # mysql port
    #volumes:
    #  - "./src:/var/www/html"
    #  - "./src:/var/www/html/custom/plugins"
    networks:
      - web
    environment:
      - XDEBUG_ENABLED=0

## ***********************************************************************
##  NETWORKS
## ***********************************************************************
networks:
  web:
    external: false
```

As you can see, you can specify any version you want using the image tag like this: `dockware/dev:6.4.11`. There is a lot of documentation on that website, so just tailor it to your own setup.

---

In the long run, in order to ensure quality of work, I do recommend you automate your testing & just use a CI to run the tests across multiple versions of Shopware 6. [Here](https://github.com/shopgate/shopware6-webcheckout/blob/1.1.1/.gitlab-ci.yml) is an example of how I run Postman tests on multiple versions of SW6 using Gitlab. You could setup something similar with unit or integration tests for your plugin.